# Does google scripts have a Trimmean method?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am creating a Google Apps Script in Google Drive that loads the same data type from multiple youtube videos (uploaded by same channel) and need to create a trimmed mean of from that array of data. I am pushing all that pull data into

```
var = videoStats;
```

And I am trying to figure out how to create a spur of the moment trimmed average (average of a data set after eliminating top and bottom X outliers). Here is what I have so far:

```
 //creating new variable and looping through to create a trimmed mean eliminating top/bottom 40%
  var sortedVidStats = videoStats.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
  for(n=0; i < sortedVidStats.items.length; i++) {
    
  }
```

Because it's a Google Apps Script, all of this is happening in the same defined function, but is there a Google Apps Script method that already performs this calculation?

Comment: no it doesnt as thats not part of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some additional searching for a function to trim mean based on existing Javascript libraries. I wanted to post this here as a resolution for how to create a trimmean function in javascript

```
function getTrimmedMean(data, trimAmount) {
    var trimCount = Math.floor(trimAmount*data.length);
    var trimData = data.sort().slice(trimCount, data.length-trimCount);
    return trimData.reduce((a, b) => a + b ,0)/trimData.length;
  }

  var trimVideoStats = getTrimmedMean(videoStats, 0.4);
  return trimVideoStats;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getTrimmedMean(values, trimAmount) {
    var trimCount = Math.floor(trimAmount*values.length);
    Logger.log(trimCount)
    var arr = values.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    var start = 0
    var end = 0
    if (trimCount % 2 == 0){
      start = (trimCount/2)
      end = (values.length - (trimCount/2))
    }else{
      start = ((trimCount - 1)/2)
      end =  (values.length - (trimCount - ((trimCount - 1)/2)))
    }
    arr = arr.slice(start,end)
    Logger.log(arr)
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).